# Is there any significance of the Star of David during Nynaeve's test?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In *Towers of Midnight*, Nynaeve finally takes her Aes Sedai test. One of the triggers in the test is "two triangles overlapped", which is like the Star of David. Is there any significance to this symbol being used?

Comment: https://13depository.blogspot.co.uk/2002/03/freemasonry-and-wheel-of-time.html